# SF short story about aliens with a system for finding habitable worlds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a short story, probably from a pulp magazine from the 60s-70s, where alien explorers land on a dead earth, wondering what happened to everyone.

They have technology to revive the dead, so they find a few human corpses, and revive them one at a time, starting with the oldest, a modern era drunk, who thinks he's having a bad trip. They put him down, and go on to revive the most recent human, who turns out to figure things out all too quickly, and proceeds to scare the heck out of the aliens by looking at them, and directly asking:
"Did you guys just stumble here, or do you have a system?"

Turns out humanity was on a godlike tech tier, advanced well beyond the aliens level, but we had never managed to figure out how to find habitable worlds any other way than to stumble into them or terraform, so when a major event threatened all of populated terran space, there was nowhere to go, so they turned off the lights, put everything on sleep mode, and just let themselves die, in the hope that a future Alien civilization might revive humanity long enough to reboot the whole thing in the future.

And now the aliens came, woke up ONE human, and since they had a nice little system for discovering habitable planets, it finally became possible for humanity to wake up and actually expand past the little bubble of space it had found itself stuck in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is A.E. van Vogt's "[Resurrection](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63317)" (originally published as "The Monster" in [*Astounding*, August 1948](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v41n06_1948-08_cape1736)).

The
The aliens actually wake two humans before the one who asks them if they have a system.  (A system is required because only 1 of every 200 000 stars has an inhabitable planet.)  The first is an Egyptian mummy, who thinks he has been raised into the afterlife.  The second, as you note, is a drunk:

> The second man stood up palely, and trembled with fear. "My God, I swear I won't touch the stuff again. Talk about pink elephants—"
>
> Yoal was curious. "To what *stuff* do you refer, revived one?"
>
> "The old hooch, the poison in the old hip pocket flask, the juice they gave me at that speak... my lordie!"

The third rapidly realizes what's going on:

> The third man sat up, and looked at them thoughtfully. "From the stars?" he said finally. "Have you a system, or was it blind chance?"

It is the fourth human revived who has superhuman abilities, beginning with vanishing as soon as he is revived.  He later reappears to converse with the Ganae:

> He stopped as he came to the screen, reached out and touched it with his fingers. It flared, blurred with changing colors; the colors grew brighter, and extended in an intricate pattern all the way from his head to the ground. The blur cleared. The colors drew back into the pattern. The pattern faded into invisibility. The man was through the screen.
>
> He laughed, a soft sound; then sobered. "When I first wakened," he said, "I was curious about the situation. The question Was, what should I do with you?"
>
> The words had a fateful ring to Enash on the still morning air of that planet of the dead. A voice broke the silence, a voice so strained and unnatural that a moment passed before he recognized it as belonging to Captain Gorsid.
>
> "Kill him!"
>
> When the blasters ceased their effort, the unkillable thing remained standing.

Earth and the only other human colony, Castor, had been wiped out by a cosmological disaster:

> "What did happen?"
>
> The man changed color. The emotions of that far day thickened his voice. "A nucleonic storm. It swept in from outer space. It brushed this edge of our galaxy. It was about ninety light-years in diameter, beyond the farthest limits of our power. There was no escape from it. We had dispensed with spaceships, and had no time to construct any. Castor, the only star with planets ever discovered by us, was also in the path of the storm."

In the end the last human has the opportunity to restart humanity:

> Enash sagged to the floor. They had missed more than one point, he realized. The man had awakened, realized the situation; and, when he vanished, he had gone to the ship, and there discovered the secret of the locator and possibly the secret of the reconstructor—if he didn’t know it previously. By the time he reappeared, he already had from them what he wanted. All the rest must have been designed to lead them to this act of desperation.
>
> In a few moments, now, *he* would be leaving the ship secure in the knowledge that shortly no alien mind would know his planet existed. Knowing, too, that his race would live again, and this time never die.

Comment: Thank you! That was it!

Comment: You're welcome!  Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left below the voting arrows.

Comment: This seems to be the tenth time this story has been identified here! I wonder what story holds the record. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstory-identification%5dis%3aa%20vogt%20resurrection&searchOn=3